# Alkaline diet afect cancer?

Tags: nutrition, cancer, alkaline-diet

I have heard that if you have an alkaline diet it actually prevents/stops cancer.

It is not mandatory to eat all alkaline things but to balance it so that the body does not get to acidic from food.

**So in the alkalines we would find:**

- Water (with a high ph)
- Watermelon
- Lemon
- Asparagus
- Onions
- etc

**And in the acidic:**

- Meat
- Coffee
- Sugar Drinks
- etc

**From wikipedia:**

```
    Alternative medicine

    Alternative medicine practitioners who have promoted the alkaline 
    diet have advocated its use in the treatment of various medical 
    conditions including cancer.
```

There is also a quote about an article but sadly the link is broken.

```
    While it has been proposed that this diet can help increase energy,
    lose weight, and treat cancer and heart disease, there is no evidence 
    to support any of these claims.[12]
```

Comment: The CAM people keep telling us that very acid food like lemons is alkaline. What definition of alkalinity do they use? As for the alkalinity of the food making any difference, what happens when it gets to the stomach, which is filled with hydrochloric acid (pH ~2). It even dissolves bones!

Comment: @hdhondt: I did see *once* someone claim that they did NOT mean "acidic" by pH, but by another method. However, I haven't seen this claim repeated, and it seems a pretty obvious point to repeat to prevent criticism, so it doesn't seem to be canon.

Comment: I'm rethinking the "duplicate" post here, because the related claim is explicitly not about diet, although the answers there probably cover it.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Not news but there seems to be a paper/leaflet that was written in 1984 about high Ph treatment for cancer. Really simple and straight it claims that cancer just disappears after some heavy dosage of supplements. From what I can tell this idea started partly with the observation of *cultures without significant incidence of cancer [I]*.

[image]

In this image taken from [global cancer map](http://globalcancermap.com/) we can see that there are frontiers to cancer. And its not just money. I dare to say that food is one of those frontiers.

**[The High pH Therapy for Cancer
Tests on Mice and Humans
  A. KEITH BREWER, Ph.D.
A.. Keith Brewer Science Library, 325 N. Central Ave., Richland Center, WI 53581](http://www.cancer-coverup.com/brewer/default.html)**

> BREWER, A. K. The high pH therapy for cancer tests on mice and humans.
>   PHARMACOL BIOCHEM BEHAV 21: Suppl. 1, 1-5. 1984.---Mass spectrographic
>   and isotope studies have shown that potassium, rubidium, and
>   especially cesium are most efficiently taken up by cancer cells. This
>   uptake was enhanced by Vitamins A and C as well as salts of zinc and
>   selenium. The quantity of cesium taken up was sufficient to raise the
>   cell to the 8 pH range. Where cell mitosis ceases and the life of the
>   cell is short. Tests on mice fed cesium and rubidium showed marked
>   shrinkage in the tumor masses within 2 weeks. In addition, the mice
>   showed none of the side effects of cancer. Tests have been carried out
>   on over 30 humans. In each case the tumor masses disappeared. Also all
>   pains and effects associated with cancer disappeared within 12 to 36
>   hr; the more chemotherapy and morphine the patient had taken, the
>   longer the withdrawal period. Studies of the food intake in areas
>   where the incidences of cancer are very low showed that it met the
>   requirements for the high pH therapy.

[I] Clark, J., Hunza in the Himalayas, National Geographic, 72, 38-45; 1963

Comment: Posting outdated research and maps doesn't really help to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

> **There is no scientific literature establishing the benefit of an alkaline diet for the prevention of cancer at this time (2011).**
>
> The effectiveness of some chemotherapeutic agents is markedly influenced by pH. Numerous agents such as epirubicin and adriamycin require an alkaline media to be more effective. Others, such as cisplatin, mitomycin C, and thiotepa, are more cytotoxic in an acid media. Cell death correlates with acidosis and intracellular pH shifts higher (more alkaline) after chemotherapy may reflect response to chemotherapy. It has been suggested that inducing metabolic alkalosis may be useful in enhancing some treatment regimes by using sodium bicarbonate, carbicab, and furosemide. Extracellular alkalinization by using bicarbonate may result in improvements in therapeutic effectiveness.

(emphasis mine)

***Source:*** Schwalfenberg GK. [The alkaline diet: is there evidence that an alkaline pH diet benefits health?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22013455) J Environ Public Health. 2011 Oct 12;2012:727630. doi: [10.1155/2012/727630](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2012/727630). PubMed PMID: 22013455.